# See exact server version in eclipse "Servers"

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, eclipse-plugin

I have added a Tomcat Server to my environment over the `add server` bar. However, when I do not know the exact version of the server, even when I have a closer look at the server properties:

[image]

How to display the **exact** server version of tomcat in eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK you cannot see directly the exact tomcat version in eclipse, but if if you start tomcat through the eclipse in console you should see the line with tomcat version. Something like that:

```
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.29
```